# importfolder errors in latest version of h2o

Tags: h2o

can someone help with h2o.importfolder error for h2o 3.29 and above ,it works with h2o3.28 and below

dataingest.hex <- h2o.importFolder(path = 's3://h2o_test/', pattern=".*\.snappy\.parquet$")

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http:/xxxxxxxxx:45820/3/ParseSetup) water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Column separator mismatch. One file seems to use " " and the other uses "\001"." [2] "

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, : ERROR MESSAGE: Column separator mismatch. One file seems to use " " and the other uses " ".